# Why do I need the array name while cycling through an array in this example?

Tags: javascript

So, I understand everything in this example but one thing. 
In the search function why do I need to write

```
if (friends[key].firstName === name)
```

instead of

```
if (key.firstName === name)
```

I believe when the objects are grabbed one by one so it seem redundant to write "friends[key].firstName"

Doesn't the loop already only have one object at time and just compares it to the name parameter?

---

```
var friends = {};
friends.bill =  {
    firstName: "Bill",
    lastName: "Gates",
    number: "(206) 555-5555",
    address: ['One Microsoft Way','Redmond','WA','98052']
};
friends.steve = {
    firstName: "Steve",
    lastName: "Ballmer",
    number: "(206) 444-5555",
    address: ['One Microsoft Way','Redmond','WA','98052']
};

var list = function(friends) {
    for (var key in friends) {
        console.log(key);
    }
};

var search = function(name) {
    for (var key in friends) {
        if (friends[key].firstName === name) {
            console.log(friends[key]);
            return friends[key];
        }
    }
 };

search("Steve");
```

Comment: As much as I hate to say "because that's how it works"... that's how it works. `for..in` loops iterate over the keys of an object.

Comment: ...and it works that way because otherwise you wouldn't have access to the key at all. This way you get both, even though you need to type a bit more in the most common case.

Comment: Niet - you mean if cycles through the key and values?

Comment: If you are wondering how a statement or expression works in JS, I recommend to read the MDN documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because with a for...in loop, the first variable (`key` in this case) represents the name of the property, not the value itself. This is a very common misunderstanding for people coming from languages with for...each loops (often syntactically very similar, but serve a completely different purpose in that they are used for iterating over collections, unlike a for...in loop which is used for iterating over the properties of an object), in which the variable directly represents the pulled value in the current iteration.

Comment: OK. So, when I go through this I am actually cycling though the keys (aka the objects, which have key value pairs). In order for JS to compare it needs to know the array(friends), the key (the key in key value pairs) and the value (in the key value pair). I guess I didn't understand the for loop was only looping the key(the friends listed only) I thought it was cycling through all the key values not the (friends)

Comment: *"when I go through this I am actually cycling though the keys (aka the objects, which have key value pairs). In order for JS to compare it needs to know the array(friends) [...]"* You got the terminology mixed up. `friends` is not an array, it is an *object*. It has a couple of properties which themselves are objects as well. `for..in` iterates over the **property names** of the object (e.g. `bill`, `steve`, etc) and `friends[key]` lets you access the property **value** (i.e. one of the objects contained in `friends`).

Comment: Thank you. Right, Friends = object and the keys are also objects("Bill and "Steve".

Comment: The key is the property name, represented as a string which you use to get the property value, but yes, that's the idea.

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript, there is no `foreach` like in other languages.
The `for (... in ...)` construct is meant for iterating over the **keys in an object**, not the values in an array.
If you use `for (... in ...)` on an array, the "keys" will be the array indexes as strings (such as `"0"`, `"1"`, etc...), which is why you can technically use it for an array, but it's definitely not the recommended way.

The most common way to iterate over an array is to use `array.forEach(function(value, i) { ... })`, which is simply a helper method (and part of ES5).

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var key in friends) {
```

`friends` is your object, and you are looping the object saving the key of the object in your `var key`. so key just holds the key you are currently looping: `steve` or `bill`. To access the object, you use object[key], so `friends[key]` is the correct usage

If you don't like this, you could try to use:

```
var keys=Object.keys(friends);
for(var i=0;i<keys.length;i++){
    var friend=friends[keys[i]];
    console.log(friend.firstName);
}
```